# Redirect to custom 404 page using .htaccess and country location (in website url)

Tags: php, html, error-handling, http-status-code-404

I would like to get some advices on how to redirect to a custom 404 page.
I know that we must type : ErrorDocument 404 /page404.php in the .htaccess file. This is done.
But what I need to do is the page404.php to refer to a French error page or an English one using the previous URL (before the user got lost) which is supposed to contain _fr/... or _en/... and I don't really know how to do it. Plus, my .htaccess file isn't working.

I've tried to use the stristr function but doesn't seem to be working. So that's why I'm coming to you guys.

Thank you in advance, have a nice day !

Answer (score 0):

assuminging that your using wordpress I would personally use the plugin called redirection. https://wordpress.org/plugins/redirection/. Here you can easily set your own custom 404, 301 pages. I have used it with mutiple sites now and cant complain. hope this helps.